# Modify styles in OneNote 2010

Tags: formatting, styles, microsoft-onenote

I'm running **OneNote 2010** and wondering if there is a way to edit the default styles?

If you change the default font, the styles won't be changed. Is there any template, registry key or file that allows for the styles to modified?

[image: styles in onenote 14]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get an add-in that will allow you to customize the styles in Onenote.  Haven't tried it myself but the comments indicate it works as stated.

Onetastic Custom Styles
http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?i=update-for-onetastic-1-3-0#custom-styles

Onetastic Download
http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=download

Versions available for Onenote 2010 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: I have tried Onetastic and it does allow creating custom styles (pity that defining custom keyboard shortcuts to use them efficiently isn't there, perhaps in a future version.) It also only applies to new pages, and doesn't change existing ones.

Comment: Sir, you made my life better. And I just found that it has this Onecalendar feature which is just amazing!!!

Answer (score 17):

Apparently, you can't (according to the "[Can Styles be Modified in OneNote 2010?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_other-mso_2010/can-styles-be-modified-in-onenote-2010/9353807b-a784-4a4a-9458-a272d23b6c49)" discussion in "[Ask the Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us)"). Also, the "*Editing improvements*" section in the "[What's new in OneNote 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20140520111902/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/what-s-new-in-onenote-2010-HA010380196.aspx)" web page says the following:

> - **Gallery of basic Styles**    OneNote 2010 adds a quick gallery of basic
>     note-taking styles, such as Heading 1, 2, 3. While not intended to match the
>     complexity of a word processor's style gallery, these basic styles provide a
>     quick and easy way to apply a consistent structure and appearance to
>     recurring types of notes (for example, class or meeting notes).

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, the fact that styles can't be customized or re-ordered is annoying. However, it is actually possible to customize the "Normal" style's font characteristics.

Go to `File, Options, General` and then you can specify the font characteristics under `Default font`.

Also, you can apply the Normal style using the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. I find this is useful for getting back to the regular style after using some special formatting.